# Listing always display same result Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need help with my code, sorry for this easy questions because I am very new to python especially when it comes to listing. So what I want for my result is that the two names would be in the leaderboard list. (It will have more names in the textfile in the future)
So can anyone help me to display different names in the list thank you.

```
scoring = {"Name": "", "WinStreak": 0}
leaderboard = []
count = 0
tester = 0

with open("testing2.txt", "r") as fileText:
    for line in fileText:
        scoring["Name"] = line.split()[0]
        winning = int(line.split()[2])
        scoring["WinStreak"] = winning
        leaderboard.append(scoring)


for display in leaderboard:
    print(display["Name"], "-", display["WinStreak"])
```

*testing2.txt*

```
John , 2
Michael , 3
```

*Actual Outcome*

```
Michael - 3
Michael - 3
```

*Expected Output*

```
John - 2
Michael - 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the same dictionary you created before the loop.
That's why you end up with list of multiple dictionaries which reference the same object.

Try instead:

```
with open("testing2.txt", "r") as fileText:
    for line in fileText:
        name = line.split()[0]
        winning = int(line.split()[2])
        leaderboard.append({"Name": name, "WinStreak": winning})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Comment: Happy to help! :)